# If $(X,d)$ and $(X,k)$ are metric spaces. Are $(X, \max(d,k))$ and $(X, \min(d,k))$ metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces

How can I prove that if $(X,d)$ and $(X,k)$ are metric spaces then $(X, \max(d,k))$ and $(X, \min(d,k))$ are metric spaces?

I try to replace j as $j=\min(d,k)$ or $j=\max(d,k)$ and prove that $j$ is positive definiteness, symmetric and satisfies the triangle inequality.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Which parts were you able to prove, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck in triangule inequality.
if d,k,l ∈ X then, j(d,k)=max(d,k)=max(d-l,k-l) ...

Comment: I have already started to solve the inequality, I have to do the 6 possible cases for the values of d, k, l right? For example, d<k<l and and so on.  My question now is how do I prove that the other two conditions are met?

Comment: $d, k l$ are points in a space, not real numbers. Statements like "$d < k < l$" make no sense as most metric spaces do not come with an order operator "$<$".

Comment: So how could you approach the problem more generally?